# Vertical and Horizontal Group by in sql

Tags: sql

please consider table below (TableName: Sale)

```
ID     Customer     Year     Amount
1         A         2012      1000
2         B         2012      2000
3         A         2012      1500
4         C         2013      1000
5         B         2013      2000
```

I'm looking for a query which groups the data by `Customer` and shows the sums of `Amount` having `Year` equal to 2012 and 2013 (distinctly), so that it returns:

```
Customer       Year2012      Year2013
A                2500           0
B                2000         2000
C                0            1000
```

Comment: Do you have just 2012 and 2013?

Comment: if query can support more years is much better. but the queary that can support only two years is adorable too.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

try this:

```
SELECT Customer,ISNULL([2012],0)as [2012],ISNULL([2013],0)as [2013]
FROM (
    SELECT 
       Customer,[Year] as [year], Amount
    FROM Mytest
) as s
PIVOT(SUM(AMOUNT)
      FOR Year IN ([2012], [2013])) AS PVTTable
```

OUTPUT:

```
Customer    2012    2013
A          2500      0
B          2000     2000
C           0       1000
```

Answer (score 0):

```
select  Customer,
    SUM(case when Year = '2012' then Amount else 0 end) as 'Year2012',
    SUM(case when Year = '2013' then Amount else 0 end) as 'Year2013'
from Sale
group by Customer;
```

SQL Fiddle - http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/f560b/4

Answer (score -1):

**Execute the following code:**

```
SELECT * FROM customer 
PIVOT(SUM(Amount) FOR Year IN ([2012],[2013]))
AS PVTTable
```

Comment: Care to explain why the OP should drop their Primary Key column?